# Question on countability of family of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{H}(\mathbb{C})$ a family of holomorphic functions such that for every $z \in \mathbb{C}$ the set $\{f(z): f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is countable, my question is if $\mathcal{F}$ is necessary countble.

I don't have any idea from where to start so any tips or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, the question you ask has name and surname: it is called *Wetzel's problem*. To that extent, we can mention the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wetzel%27s_problem), which has a brief historical overview of the problem, as well as [the article by Erdös](https://www.bsmath.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1964-04.pdf), which proves the following:

*The conclusion of the problem (i.e., there are only countably many  analytic functions in the family) is equivalent to the continuum hypothesis **not** holding.*

Therefore, there is no simple answer to your question. The article by Erdös contains a beautiful proof of such equivalence, which I recommend that anyone who likes mathematics checks.

On the other hand, if you replace "countable" by "finite" everywhere, there is a simple answer: yes, the family must be finite, given that $\{f(z) \colon f \in \mathcal{F}\}$ is finite for all $z \in \mathbb{C}.$ The proof, which is fairly simple, is as follows:

Suppose there is an infinite sequence $\{f_i\}_{i \ge 1} \subset \mathcal{F}$ of pairwise distinct analytic functions. Let first $B_{i,j} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon f_i(z) = f_j(z)\}.$ As all functions are analytic and distinct pairwise, the set $B_{i,j}$ is at most countable. Thus, the set

$$B = \cup_{i,j \ge 1, i \neq j} B_{i,j}$$

Is also countable. Now let $A_N = \{z \in \mathbb{C} \colon |\{f(z) \colon f \in \mathcal{F}\}| = N\}.$ As $\cup_{N \ge 1} A_N = \mathbb{C},$ there is $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $A_M$ is uncountable.

On the other hand, as $A_M$ is uncountable and $B$ is countable, there is at least a point $z_0 \in A_M \cap B^{c}.$ But this is a contradiction, as $z_0 \in B^{c}$ implies that $f_i(z_0) \neq f_j(z_0), \forall i\neq j,$ and thus $z_0 \not \in A_M.$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is really good and complete. I haven't read Erdös article but reading Wikipedia's page on the problem I've shown that the proof following Erdös reasoning is also avalible in the book _Proofs from THE BOOK_ by Aigner and Ziegler and it is very well explained there.

Comment: I am glad to help :) Yep, it is in the ‘Proofs from THE BOOK’, and the version there is explained to great detail, also a really nice source

Comment: LOL this means I've just spent the last couple of hours trying to prove the negation of the Continuum Hypothesis. No wonder....